# Abrir documento pdf via intent?

Tags: android, android-studio, intent, android-intent

Tenho uma aplicação que gera um pdf através de um botão e ao clicar no botão abre um alertdialog onde nomeio meu arquivo e por conseguinte e aberto um snackbar com o titulo " Deseja abrir o arquivo ?" e um botão "sim" e ao clicar ele abre o diretório de download e não o documents e ao clicar em algum PDF ele não abre e retorna ao aplicativo. O que pode ser ?

Segue trecho do botão do snackbar:

```
 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(constraintLayout,"Deseja abrir arquivo :", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction(" ", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String pdf = nomepdf.getText().toString();
                File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(file+"/"+pdf+".pdf")), "application/pdf");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);


                Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File !");
                startActivity(chooser);


            }

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Remova setDataAndType
Adicione uri e type separadamente da seguinte forma:

```
Intent.setType("application/pdf") // identifica o tipo de arquivo que vc quer compartilhar, isso permite que a lista de programas exibidas seja correta(so exibira apps capazes de lerem pdf
Intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STREAM, uri) //adiciona o arquivo a ser compartilhado
Intent.setAction(ACTION_SEND)
Intent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

Comment: Você pode enriquecer sua resposta explicando pra que serve essas linhas de código.

Comment: Continuou da mesma forma, por que será ?

Comment: Editei a resposta talvez ajude

Comment: Acho que funcionou, mas ao executar o Intent chooser , recebo a mensagem que os aplicativos para leitura de PD foram bloqueados , desativados ou não instalados. O leitor nativo do android não funciona e o leitor que tenho instalado tambem não funcionou.